# Process large csv file, look up values from another csv, Python

Tags: python, csv

iam parsing csv files and I have one csv file that looks like this:

SeqID | GIs
SeqA  123  456
SeqB  999  888  777
...

What i now want to do involves a second file which functions as cross
reference, this one looks as follows:

GI  |  XIDs
123  X781
456  X676
789  X123
9999  X217

The aim is to look up the GIs of each Seq in the file that functions
as cross reference. Problem is that this cross reference file is quite
big (2.3GB). So far iam trying to solve the problem as follows:

```
def map_GI(gilist, mapped):
    with open(gilist) as infile:
      read_gi = csv.reader(infile)
      GI_list = {rows[0]:rows[1:] for rows in read_gi} # read GI list into dictionary
      XID_list = defaultdict(list) # set up XID list as empty dictionary of lists
      infile.close()
    with open(mapping_file) as mapping: # thats the cross reference
      read_mapping = csv.reader(mapping, delimiter='\t') 
      reference_mapping = list(read_reference) # write reference in list
      for k, v in GI_list.items():# iterate over GI list and mapping file
        for row in reference_mapping:
            if row[0] in v:
                XID_list[k].append(row[1]) # write found GOs into dictionary
      mapping.close()
    with open("/output.txt", 'wb') as outfile: # save mapped SeqIDs plus XIDs
      looked_up_go = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='\t')
      for key, val in XID_list.iteritems():
         looked_up_go.writerow([key] + val)
```

The desired output should be a file listing the original SeqIDs and respective
XIDs:

SeqID | XIDs
SeqA  X781  X676

The code works, but it takes forever (and probably even longer). Writing
the cross reference into a list is not super smart, iam aware of that.
I found some related questions, but still not what iam looking for.

Iam grateful for any comments, suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have one small file and one big file, the usual answer is to find a way to iterate the big file once, lazily, while iterating the small file repeatedly (by reading it into memory if possible, re-reading the file if not), instead of the other way around.

So, start with something like this:

```
def map_GI(gilist, mapped):
    with open(gilist) as infile:
        read_gi = csv.reader(infile)
        GI_list = {rows[0]:rows[1:] for rows in read_gi} # read GI list into dictionary
    with open(mapping_file) as mapping: # thats the cross reference
        read_mapping = csv.reader(mapping, delimiter='\t') 
        for gid, xids in read_mapping:
            for gi_seqid, gi_gids in GI_list:
                GI_list[seqid] = [xids if gi_gid == gid else gi_gid for gi_gid in gi_gids] 
    with open("/output.txt", 'wb') as outfile: # save mapped SeqIDs plus XIDs
        looked_up_go = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='\t')
        for key, val in XID_list.iteritems():
            looked_up_go.writerow([key] + val)
```

However, you can do a lot better in this case if the small file is small enough: just build a reverse mapping, so you can look up which rows have to be modified instead of walking the whole list:

```
    with open(gilist) as infile:
        read_gi = csv.reader(infile)
        GI_list = {rows[0]:rows[1:] for rows in read_gi} # read GI list into dictionary
        revdict = defaultdict(list)
        for seqid, gids in GI_list.iteritems():
            for gid in gids:
                revdict[gid].append(seqid)
    with open(mapping_file) as mapping: # thats the cross reference
        read_mapping = csv.reader(mapping, delimiter='\t') 
        for gid, xids in read_mapping:
            for seqid in revmap[gid]:
                GI_list[seqid] = [(xids if gi_gid == gid else gi_gid) 
                                  for gi_gid in gi_gids]
```

(In fact, even if the small file weren't small enough to fit into memory, the same strategy would work using a `dbm` instead of a `dict` for `revdict`.)

Comment: So obvious, i was sitting at work and simply didn't see it, thanks a lot.